# Display another property of TreeModule object in ng2-tree module instead of value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tree

in angular5 i import TreeModule from ng2-tree to use its tree selector 
how can i customize display of it? like display name property value instead of value property or show an image inside of each node.